# How do I get Windows SE RDP & CONSOLE using scripts?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was trying to create a script to record PC/SERVER user login,logoff,login duration,username,sessionname,date,time. I'm stuck at the sessioname because it display the result wrongly.

This is the command in the bat script which is exactly the same when I type manually in cmd:

```
echo %SESSIONNAME%
pause
```

If I use a bat file, it show wrong result:

```
W:\IT Tools>echo
ECHO is on.

W:\IT Tools>pause
Press any key to continue . . . _
```

By using cmd, it is able to show the correct result:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>echo %SESSIONNAME%
RDP-Tcp#39

C:\Users\Administrator>_
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query the session info use `QWinSta` or `Query Session` instead.

I assume this is a cmd script to be used as a Windows logon script. If so, %UserName% and %ComputerName% will be populated with the info for those items already.

Example `Query Session` to return the session info for the current user on the server the script is run on:

```
Query Session %UserName%
```

To get the session info you want out to be used in a combined output we'll want to put the command into a `For` Loop.

We'll also use `find` to ignore unneeded lines.

```
For %%_ IN ('
  Query Session %UserName%
  ^| Find /I "%UserName%"
') DO (
  Set "_SessionID=%%_"
)
Echo.Session = "%_SessionID%"
```

The login script below will output most of what you were looking for, saving it to a CSV in the directory where your login script runs from (usually netlogon -- Note if not Netlogon, you need to make sure the domain users will have rights to write to that directory)  this is done using the `%0` variable which holds the script's name and path `~dp` specifies to just use the full path, we'll create and write logs to a logs subdirectory there)

```
@(SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  Call :Get-DateTime
  Set "_LogPath=%~0Logs"
  IF Not Exist "!_LogPath!\" (
    MD "!_LogPath!\" )
  Set "_Log=!_LogPath!\RDPLogins_!_IsoDate!.log"
  Set "Write-Output=CALL :Write-Output "
)

Call :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /b 0
)

:Main
  For %%_ IN ('
    Query Session %UserName%
    ^| Find /I "%UserName%"
  ') DO (
    Set "_SessionID=%%_"
  )
  %Write-Output% LogOn,%username%,%_SessionID%,%_IsoDate%,%_IsoTime%,%#TMinutes%
Goto :EOF

:Write-Output
  Echo(%*
  Echo(%*>>"%_Log%"
GOTO :EOF

:Get-DateTime
  FOR /F "Tokens=1-7 delims=MTWFSmtwfsouehrandit:-\/. " %%A IN (
    "%DATE% %TIME: =0%"
  ) DO (
    FOR /F "Tokens=2-4 Skip=1 Delims=(-)" %%a IN ('
      ECHO.^| DATE
    ') DO (
      SET "_%%~a=%%~A"
      SET "_%%~b=%%~B"
      SET "_%%~c=%%~C"
      SET "_HH=%%~D"
      SET "_Mn=%%~E"
      SET "_SS=%%~F"
      SET "_Ms=%%~G"
      SET /a "#TMinutes=((1%%~D - (2%%~D-1%%~D))*60)+(1%%~E - (2%%~E-1%%~E))"
      SET /a "#TSeconds=((((1%%~D - (2%%~D-1%%~D))*60)+(1%%~E - (2%%~E-1%%~E)))*60)+(1%%~F - (2%%~F-1%%~F))"
    )
  )
  SET "_IsoTime=%_HH%.%_Mn%.%_SS%"
  SET "_IsoDate=%_yy%-%_mm%-%_dd%"
  SET "Get-DateTime=CALL :Get-DateTime"
GOTO :EOF
```